# References to C functions determined at compile time

Tags: c, makefile

I am trying to think of the most elegant solution for a C program I am currently writing. Basically, I have a small core program and then lots of additional "modules" which can be called by the core program and contain most of the functionality. The idea is that the core and and each of these modules is independent.

The inclusion of these modules is determined at compile time and once I register them then the core has function pointers to the modules which it can then use.... but what is the best way of making these modules known in the first place for registration with minimal dependencies? I am currently using a "module factory" type approach, which knows about the modules and is called by the core to obtain their details for registration. But I was wondering if, through make and the preprocessor if there might be a better way of "auto-discovering" which modules have been compiled in with the core?

In the past I have used dynamically loaded libraries but in this case my modules need to be compiled in so dynamically loading a bunch of libraries from a directory and solving it that way is not an option.

Comment: How is it decided which modules will be compiled into the application? Can that process add preprocessor macros for the compiler? Or autogenerate some file with a module table?

Comment: Joachim - it is currently determined explicitly by the makefile. I thought that I might be able to pass the present modules via preprocessor declares into a "factory" - I would rather not autogenerate a file but passing these details via the preprocessor would possibly allow me to create a module table based upon that information. I guess other people will have adopted a similar design approach at some point so there must be experience of what worked best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if I understand the question, but I suppose you could as always create something semi-obscure with macros. I wouldn't really recommend it, but for what it is worth...:

Suppose you have one module called "module_this" and another called "module_that". There's also "module_missing" which isn't compiled with the program.

You could then create something like:

module_this.h

```
#ifndef MODULE_THIS                // your ordinary header guard
#define MODULE_THIS module_this,   // add a function name plus a comma

void module_this (void);
#endif
```

module_that.h

```
#ifndef MODULE_THAT                // your ordinary header guard
#define MODULE_THAT module_that,   // add a function name plus a comma

void module_that (void);
#endif
```

core.c

```
#include "something that includes all linked files.h" // generate this externally

#ifndef MODULE_THIS     // this module is compiled
#define MODULE_THIS     // so it wont get defined here
#endif

#ifndef MODULE_MISSING  // module that was not compiled
#define MODULE_MISSING  // will get defined as empty macro
#endif

#ifndef MODULE_THAT     // this module is compiled
#define MODULE_THAT     // so it wont get defined here
#endif


typedef void(*module_t)(void);  // your function pointer type to use

static const module_t MODULE_TABLE [] = // list of all existing modules
{
  MODULE_THIS                           // note absence of commas
  MODULE_MISSING
  MODULE_THAT
};

#define MODULES_N ( sizeof(MODULE_TABLE) / sizeof(module_t) )

...
printf("There are %d modules in the project.", MODULES_N);
```

This relies on a header file which is created from scripts/the make file, containing a number of `#include`.

Comment: Yer, I think something along those lines is probably what I am going to have to do - although as you say it is not particularly elegant.